# cell array is not supported for my hdl coder in matlab,, how to fix it

Tags: matlab-deployment

while converting my .m file in matlab to vhdl using hdl coder iam getting cell array is not supported . How to fix these errors while fixed point conversion

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, cell arrays are not supported as input arguments or return values. This is a limitation in MATLAB codegen products such as MATLAB Coder and HDL Coder. You'll need to modify or wrap the function to use supported types. A commonly used option is to replace cell arrays with structures. See: 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63288-removing-cell-arrays-from-code

Comment: Thank you  very much scai, for ur reply.May i use zeros function to create array with zeros instead of creating cell array ..

Comment: @Sri, I believe zeros is a function supported by HDL Coder. See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012b/hdlcoder/gs/example-generating-hdl-code-from-matlab-code.html

Comment: when i replaced cell function with zeros function . i got this error showing "Conversion to double from cell is not possible."